# How to use exiftool to write date tags according to file path?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, date

I need to set the exif date tag of a bunch of photos stored with the following hierarchy:
YEAR/MONTH/DAY/IMG_something.JPG

How could I do it easily with exiftool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the command would be something like this
`ExifTool "-TAG<Directory" <DIR or FILE>`
assuming that the directory structure is numeric e.g. 2015/07/04
But there may be problems depending upon the exact tag you want to use.  Many date/time tags require a time as well as a date and I believe all the EXIF date/time tags fall into this category.  If you don't care about the actual time, you could `-TAG<$Directory 00:00:00`.  Or if you want to increment the time, you can see [this previous post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/60403/37960) for some help.

XMP tags are usually more flexible and can be used without a time.

If there is already a current time in the tag and you just want to change the date, you can use something like this
`ExifTool "-DateTimeOriginal<$Directory ${DateTimeOriginal;s/.* //" <DIR or FILE>`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried: exiftool "-CreateDate<Directory 00:00:00" -r ./ and got errors like: Warning: No writable tags set from ./2015/03/03/IMG_3472.JPG Maybe it has to do with the fact that the Directory tag starts with a ./ ?

Comment: Two things to try, mistakes on my part. If you're running on linux/mac, change the double quotes to single quotes.  Also, I forgot to add a dollar sign to the assignment because of mixing tag and text.  So try this `exiftool '-CreateDate<$Directory 00:00:00' -r ./ `   The `./` should not be a problem at all.  The program's author uses similar examples all the time and I just tested it on my Windows computer and it worked fine.