# How do I import metadata from a filename?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I'm looking for a tool (freeware if possible) that can write the metadata of a picture by parsing its filename.

**Example:**

*Filename:* `mySuperCoolPhoto_20150825.jpg`

*Extracted Metadata:* `EXIF:DateTimeOriginal: 25-08-2015`

So I need to give the tool a pattern how my filenames look like and the tool should do the rest. I'm okay with Windows and Mac tools. I was already thinking of writing my own script, but before I start I'll ask here first.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Exiftool.  The answer is similar to [this post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/how-to-use-exiftool-to-write-date-tags-according-to-file-path/) except you replace `Directory` with `Filename`.  But then you have the same problem as listed in that post.  What is the exact tag you want to write to and how are you going to handle the time portion of the tag.

Comment: The "this post" link links to this very post...?

Comment: Oooops, fixed.  Here's the link again just in case I screwed up twice

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/how-to-use-exiftool-to-write-date-tags-according-to-file-path/

Comment: Thank's man! That's exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm.