# Writing missing/incorrect Date Tags based on FileName in ExifTool?

Tags: exiftool

I'm using Linux Mint and have about 2,000 images which have either incorrect or missing EXIF Date tags. I would like to use the date contained in the filename to write the tags. I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do this in ExifTool but haven't managed to get very far unfortunately.

The files are in the format: YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg. However there are some duplicate filenames (different images though, so I can't just delete the duplicates) which are of the format YYYMMDD_HHMMSS(1).jpg. Lastly, there are some images which were shot in burst mode and are of the format YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_001.jpg.

I'm familiar with the basics of Python so was able to tidy up some other naming issues and get the files to a point where the first 15 characters of every file name adhere to the same format. So I was hoping I could somehow use just the first 15 characters of each file as input to write the tags. I think I need something along the lines of:

`exiftool '-AllDates<$Filename...'`

...but I cant figure out how to do the [advanced formatting](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#Advanced-formatting-feature) which needs to go on the end. Would someone be able to help me out?

I did see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/how-to-use-exiftool-to-write-date-tags-according-to-file-path/?newreg=c040567857b84c95a3d8195e4a9f10c2) but it didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command is mostly correct as written.  See [Exiftool FAQ #5](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q5), 3rd paragraph.

The only suggestion I have is to remove the dollar sign, as it would be unneeded for this operation.

`exiftool '-Alldates<Filename' <DirsOrFiles>`

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I can't believe I missed the FAQs while reading the documentation (fail!). Anyhow, much appreciated. =)

Comment: The documentation is extensive and it's easy to miss something.  I knew that line existed someplace but had to search through two other pages before I (re)found it in the FAQ.