# How can I batch edit metadata?

Tags: metadata, batch

I have around 2500 photos from different devices, most of them had synchronized timestamps and properly saved metadata. One device had no option to save a timestamp and metadata (even the filenames are random). I need free software that allows me to select images from a particular day and save some custom metadata to them (e.g., only the *Taken date*). It would nice if it was GUI software, but console programs are also ok. I can use Linux or Windows.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "select some portions of images and save to them some metadata".

Comment: @xiota That means that I will choose in eg 20 photos that I remember was taken in one day and save to them _Date taken_ or _Date created_ to this day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention files coming from different devices, it would probably be useful to sort files into folders based on the device from which they came.

```
exiftool '-Directory<${Make;} ${Model;}' -ext jpg .
```

You can then move the files you want to alter to a different folder to further process with `exiftool`. For instance, you might want to rename them according to date and time, then retag based on file name. See [Writing missing/incorrect Date Tags based on FileName in ExifTool?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94373/75526)

Comment: This can be done with a single exiftool command for all files, rather than running exiftool three times for each file (see [Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3)):  `exiftool '-Directory<${Make;} ${Model;}' /Dir/To/Process`  This command will also correct for characters like slashes that may create unwanted subdirectories.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.