# How to change Date Taken based in file name?

Tags: metadata, batch, filenames

I have a huge collection of photos from 1999 to 2019 and many of them don't have `Date Taken` registry, but all of them have the date in file name, like `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD`.

But when I uploaded them (400 GB) to Google Photos, they are all messy because many of them are not date organized since Google organize them by this `Date Taken` attribute.

Is there a good GUI or Console tool that can create the `Date Taken` metadata based on a date found in the file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing missing/incorrect Date Tags based on FileName in ExifTool?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94373/writing-missing-incorrect-date-tags-based-on-filename-in-exiftool)

Comment: I will have to do it in HD then, re-upload them.

Comment: @xiota that question you mentioned is about duplicated files...

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords That question mentions that some of the existing filenames are duplicates (presumably due to being taken at the same time). That's not the core of the question, though — the core of the question is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Although it does presuppose using a particular software tool (ExifTool).

Answer (score 2):

**If you're asking how to do this remotely on images stored by Google Photos, there is currently no way to do so.**

There are other questions and answers addressing how to do this on images located on your local computer using ExifTool.  For instance, [Writing missing/incorrect Date Tags based on FileName in ExifTool?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94373/)

You can use the following command:

```
exiftool '-Alldates<Filename' .
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been 5 years and still no complete answer, so I wrote a simple application to do it for future users.
https://github.com/dangphuc2470/Creation_Date_Changer